# MIME type ('text/html') is not executable and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery

In magento when I add to cart the product I show below error:

"Refused to execute script from 'http://www.example.com/ajaxcartsuper/ajaxcart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL215ZmF…r_attribute%5B139%5D=27&qty=1&product=377&related_product=&_=1478249505680' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

Comment: Thanks for the answer but for my site (Magento 2) I can't see these lines for the .htaccess file, so how can I fix it? could you please help me out it to resolve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes I solved it:
I just put the below line to my htaccess file than it works good in chrome as well as other browser

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff    
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue and when i checked root `.htaccess` file then that code already exist and i have comment that and its working fine.

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # Header set X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
 </IfModule>
```

If your server adds the `X-Content-Type-Options` header when serving the *.js files, it will force some browsers such as Chrome to perform strict checking of MIME types.

```
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

So, Remove this header to prevent browsers to performing the MIME check.