# Error in installing magento 1.9

Tags: installation, magento1.9.3

I am trying to install magento 1.9.3.4. But there are some problems in magento installation wizard. I am getting following errors in browser console.

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://<www.domain.com>/js/prototype/prototype.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
Refused to execute script from 'http://<www.domain.com>/js/prototype/validation.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
Refused to execute script from 'http://<www.domain.com>/js/scriptaculous/effects.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
Refused to execute script from 'http://<www.domain.com>/js/mage/translate.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
Refused to execute script from 'http://<www.domain.com>/js/varien/js.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
Refused to execute script from 'http://<www.domain.com>/js/varien/form.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

And the page is showing like this:
[image]

I have checked this forum and tried these:
[Click Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144143/mime-type-text-html-is-not-executable-and-strict-mime-type-checking-is-enabl)
but there are still showing the same error. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your magento folder permission is wrong fire below commands in your magento root

```
chmod -R 644 ./*

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

chmod 550 ./mage
```

Fire above for command one by one any your problem would solve