# Error when add product to cart in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, ajax

I installed a module ajax add to cart and when click add to cart, it show error

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://.../ajaxcartsuper/ajaxcart/delete/id/...' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I saw it in the head.phtml file

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php echo $this->getContentType() ?>" />
```

But i cann't fix it, please help me.

Comment: Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144143/mime-type-text-html-is-not-executable-and-strict-mime-type-checking-is-enabl

Comment: thanks for answer, but it not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

***put the below line to htaccess file***

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff    
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but it not work for me :(